# Unknown property in Angular object

Tags: java, angular, typescript, rest

While sending object to the backend **UnrecognizedPropertyException** appears. I have checked object on both frontend and backend side and it looks the same.

However when I am checking this object at frontend console I can see that it has additional property that is not defined nowhere in the project (I've tried to search it on IntelliJ ctrl + shift + f).

This property was in the object some time ago so it is possible that somehow it is cashed?
I've tried to clear cache / invalidate cache in IntelliJ / npm clean-install etc.

How can I check from where this property appears in object ?

*@JsonIgnoreProperties* is not an option in my case...

Frontend object (Angular 8 + Typescript 2.6.2):

```
export class ItemEto extends AbstractEto {
    item1: number;
    item2: number;
}

export class AbstractEto {
    id: number;
    modificationCounter: number;
}
```

Backend object (Java 8):

```
public class ItemEto extends AbstractEto {
    private long item1;
    private long item2;
}

public class AbstractEto {
    private long id;
    private long modificationCounter;
}
```

Object on console (JSON):

```
{
    "ItemEto": {
        "item1": 1,
        "item2": 2,
        "otherUnknownProperty": {
            "item3": null;
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the object initialized on the frontend?

Comment: Object is taken from service and later mapped to ItemEto type.

Comment: Can you check the data you get in the console network tab? I want to know if the server responds with that data or is it's later added on the frontend

Answer (score 0):

Either you have that "Unkown" property in **AbstractEto** or you forgot to **map** the object to **ItemEto** before you send it inside the response.

Comment: AbstractEto looks fine (I've added code snippet). I also do not see anything weird in mapping.

Comment: Did you configure this map with a profile?